# How collect / reduce java 8 stream into pojo?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce, collect

Look at the code:

```
Collection<MyDto> col = ...

MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder(); 
for (MyDto dto: col) {
    switch (dto.getType()) {
        case FIELD1:
            builder.field1(dto.getValue());
            break:
        case FIELD2:
            builder.field2(dto.getValue());
            break:
    }    
}

Some result = builder.build();
```

Is there a way to do this with streams, like:

```
Some result = col.stream().collect(...)
```

Note that all stream values are collected into sigle pojo, not collection, stream or map.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that somewhere, somehow, you need to map the possible return values of `MyDto.getType()` to property setting methods of `MyBuilder`.  Your code does that via a `switch` statement, *and that's just fine*.  You can write the reduction as a stream-based pipeline instead, but you still need to incorporate the mapping somehow.

A pretty direct way of doing that would be to construct a literal `Map`, which could be made static, final, and unmodifiable.  For instance, if you're starting with classes structured like so ...

```
class Some {
}

class MyBuilder {
    void field1(String s) { }
    void field2(String s) { }
    void field3(String s) { }
    Some build() {
        return null;
    }
}

class ValueType {}

class MyDto {
    int type;
    ValueType value;

    int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    ValueType getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

... then you might set up the reduction you describe like this:

```
public class Reduction {

    // Map from DTO types to builder methods
    private final static Map<Integer, BiConsumer<MyBuilder, ValueType>> builderMethods;

    static {
        // one-time map initialization
        Map<Integer, BiConsumer<MyBuilder, ValueType>> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put(FIELD1, MyBuilder::field1);
        temp.put(FIELD2, MyBuilder::field2);
        temp.put(FIELD3, MyBuilder::field3);
        builderMethods = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    public Some reduce(Collection<MyDto> col) {
        return col.stream()
                  // this reduction produces the populated builder
                  .reduce(new MyBuilder(),
                          (b, d) -> { builderMethods.get(d.getType()).accept(b, d); return b; })
                  // obtain the built object
                  .build();
    }
}
```

That particular implementation uses a new builder every time, but it could be modified to instead use a builder passed into `Reduction.reduce()` via a parameter, in case you want to start with some properties pre-populated, and / or retain a record of the properties with which the returned object was built.

Finally, note well that although you can hide the details in one place or another, I don't see any scope to make the overall process any simpler than the `switch`-based code you started with.

Comment: I was woking on an edit t my answer, close to this... no need I guess, 1+

Comment: We took similar approaches re: the lambda map, but I think your `reduce()` solution is more elegant and apt for a Builder Pattern than mine, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I did not compile this, but just to give you an idea:

```
 Map<Boolean, List<MyDto>> map = col.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(t -> t.getType() == FIELD2));

 map.get(false).forEach(x -> builder.field1(x.getValue()))

 map.get(true).forEach(x -> builder.field2(x.getValue()))
```

Comment: Nice one, but this will be limited to only two types. I guess you could use the `groupingBy` collector to generalise it if you have more than 2 types.

Comment: @marstran yup! in my defense the OP showed only two options anyway

Comment: I think you do need to use `groupingBy` anyway: `partitioningBy` takes a `Predicate<T>`, and `MyDto::getType` doesn't return `bool`. Or change your code to `partitioningBy(t -> t.getType() == FIELD2)`.

Comment: It does need to be `== FIELD2` though, or you apply the builder methods for the wrong partitions later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming two `MyBuilder` instances are capable of being combined/merged then you can do this with a `Collector`.

```
public class MyCollector implements Collector<MyDto, MyBuilder, Result> {

    @Override 
    public Supplier<MyBuilder> supplier() {
        return MyBuilder::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<MyBuilder, MyDto> accumulator() {
        return (builder, dto) -> {
            // Add "dto" to "builder" based on type
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<MyBuilder> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> left.merge(right);
    }

    @Override
    public Function<MyBuilder, Result> finisher() {
        return MyBuilder::build;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }

}
```

Then you could do:

```
Collection<MyDto> col = ...;
Result r = col.stream().collect(new MyCollector());
```

If you don't want to make a custom implementation of `Collector` you can use `Collector.of(...)`.

---

A different, maybe more maintainable, way to do this is to have the builder do all the work. This way all the mapping logic is in one place.

```
public class ResultBuilder {

    public static Collector<MyDto, ?, Result> resultCollector() {
        return Collector.of(ResultBuilder::new, ResultBuilder::add,
                ResultBuilder::merge, ResultBuilder::build);
    }

    public ResultBuilder add(MyDto dto) {
        // Do what is needed based on the type of "dto"
        return this;
    }

    public ResultBuilder merge(ResultBuilder other) {
        // Merge "other" into "this"
        return this;
    }

    public Result build() {
        // Build result and return it
    }

}
```

Then you could use the builder with or without streams. With streams is very similar to before:

```
Collection<MyDto> col = ...;
Result r = col.stream().collect(ResultBuilder.resultCollector());
```

Answer (score 1):

And now, for a depressingly boring answer:

## Don't do this.

Using streams to effectively map across like this makes your code less readable and maintainable in the future.  It is ill-advised to use this Java 8 feature for this purpose.

It absolutely *can* be done, as some answerers have pioneered, but that doesn't necessarily mean it *should* be done.

More concisely, your initial premise is that you can capture all of your fields in some kind of enum or structure you can `switch` on, which breaks every time you introduce or remove a field, which can be time consuming to track down.  Clever ways of getting the fields out with reflection may be *slightly* more flexible, but then you're in a more rigid setup with reflection than you may realize; if you want to map 1 to 1 this works fine, but if you want to do some data transformation, you have to be very careful about how you tweak your mapper.

All of that to say...

**Use a mapping framework instead like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) or [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer).**

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that the mapping of each `MyBuilder` method to each `MyDto` type is arbitrary, i.e. there's no way for Java to automatically know which method to call for each type: you have to tell Java which is which.

So, if each method of the builder is mapped to a different `dto.getType()` value, the simplest way of telling Java, is moving that `switch` to a general method inside `MyBuilder` that lets you inform the appropriate field, like this:

```
public MyBuilder fieldFromDto(MyDto dto) {
    switch (dto.getType()) {
        case FIELD1: return field1(dto.getValue);
        case FIELD2: return field2(dto.getValue);
        //...
```

So then you could do just this:

```
MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder();
col.stream().forEach(builder::fieldFromDto);
Some result = builder.build();
```

Another possibility would be to turn that switch into a lambda map (`Type` and `Value` being the types of `MyDto`'s fields):

```
class MyBuilder {
    public final Map<Type, Function<Value, MyBuilder>> mappings = new Map<>();
    public MyBuilder() {
        mappings.put(FIELD1, this::field1);
        mappings.put(FIELD2, this::field2);
        //...
    }
```

And then use those lambdas in a `forEach`:

```
MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder();
col.stream().forEach(dto -> builder.mappings.get(dto.getType()).apply(dto.getValue()));
Some result = builder.build();
```

Other than that, you could use reflection like some other answers proposed, but then you need to make sure that `FIELD1`, `FIELD2` etc. are actual `MyBuilder` method names, losing some flexibility.

In the end I wouldn't recommend doing any of the above. Streams are great, but sometimes they don't offer any advantage over a normal `for` loop and can make your code uglier and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I agree to all you've said. Just a note about using `col.stream().forEach(...)`... You don't need the stream here, all iterables in java implement the `forEach` method, so it's enough to do `col.forEach(...)`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Indeed. Initially I was using `.stream().sequential().forEach(...)` to avoid concurrency problems, but I dropped the `.sequential()` in the last moment (given that it's the default), leaving `.stream().forEach(...)`. You're right that usually `.stream()` is not needed here (there are exceptions: `synchronizedList(...).stream().forEach(...)` is not the same as `synchronizedList(...).forEach(...)`). I think I'll leave it that way anyways, though, since as an answer I think it makes it clearer that we're using streams to get the result.